# How to diagnose Visual Studio Code CSS outline and Go to symbol disappearance

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

For some reason, my OSX Visual Studio Code has stopped indexing CSS files.

Neither Outline nor Go to the symbol are available.

[image]

[image]

I tested and symbol and outline information still comes correctly from JS files, but not CSS. I also tested creating a new workspace and the problem persists.

How can I diagnose language service issues in Visual Studio Code and fix the problem? As far as I know, the support for CSS file indexing worked with Visual Studio Code out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a developer tools from `Help` > `Toggle Developer Tool`. It shows VS Code internal JavaScript errors and debug output.

This line gave a hint:

[image]

PostCSS Language Support extension was loaded and it broke language support for normal CSS, or stopped indexing CSS symbols. After uninstalling PostCSS support CSS symbols started to work again.